# Converting Structure into byte data and vice versa in golang

Tags: go

I am writing a Go program in which I am just geting response from server using -

```
tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
link := "address of server"
resp, err := client.Get(link)
```

Now I need to convert resp into bytes so that I can pass it to some function and other side can decode it into the same structure.
resp is a structure of http.Response type defined in http package that I can not change.

I want to convert it directly into bytes.

Is there any such function in golang which I can directly use or is there any way exist to do the same.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the [encode](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/) package from go's library. Usually I like the JSON encoding because it's very human readable, but the package supports encoding to/from many formats including binary and [gob](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) which is a format designed just for what you are trying to do.

Example from the go [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Marshal) to encode to json:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    type ColorGroup struct {
        ID     int
        Name   string
        Colors []string
    }
    group := ColorGroup{
        ID:     1,
        Name:   "Reds",
        Colors: []string{"Crimson", "Red", "Ruby", "Maroon"},
    }
    b, err := json.Marshal(group)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write(b)
}
```

Example from the go [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) to decode from json:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var jsonBlob = []byte(`[
        {"Name": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
        {"Name": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
    ]`)
    type Animal struct {
        Name  string
        Order string
    }
    var animals []Animal
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &animals)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", animals)
}
```

Comment: Your approach for marshaling this particular structure is correct but for                                                                          resp, err := client.Get(link)                                                 resp is a structure which contain resp.Body field , if you tried to marshal this whole structure then this field will be converted into null value , so here it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
```

You can use this as bytes or simply convert ir to string like this

`bodyString := string(bodyBytes`)

Answer (score 0):

http.Response is too involved to be converted to bytes and then be restored.
But for simple struct, you may consider using [gob](https://blog.golang.org/gobs-of-data) which is designed for:

> To transmit a data structure across a network or to store it in a file, it must be encoded and then decoded again.

Answer (score 0):

`DumpResponse` function from `net/http/httputil` package might be useful.

https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#example-DumpResponse

The documentation provides an example.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I misunderstood your question. But here is an example of how to convert a struct to a []byte and vice versa.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type S struct{ s string }
    st := S{"address of server"}
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", st, st.s) //main.S test
    //convert struct to []byte
    sl := []byte(st.s)
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", sl, sl) //[]uint8 [97 100 ... 114]
    //convert []byte to struct
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%s", sl)
    st2 := S{s}
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", st2, st2.s) //main.S test
}
```

Comment: You are converting the _field_ s of struct S to a byte array and vice versa.